# React Hooks - Can't get nested data from state

Tags: javascript, axios, react-hooks

I'm still having difficulty with my state "pokeData". I'm calling pokeapi and setting the state and am able to obtain 1 level of nested data, anything more and I get an error and my state becomes undefined. Below is a pic of the console and what the data structure shows.

My problem is at this line code: `

```js
<img src={pokeData.sprites.front_default} alt=""/>
```

`

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const Card = () => {
    const [ pokeData, setPokeData ] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        axios
            .get('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/151')
            .then(res => {
                setPokeData(res.data);
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
                
            })
    }, []);

console.log(pokeData);

    return (
        <div className="card">
            <h1 className="poke-name">{pokeData.name}</h1>
            <img src={pokeData.sprites.front_default} alt=""/>     
        </div>
    )
}
    
export default Card;
```

[Console Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Gi79.png)

[Data in "pokeData" state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVWu1.png)

Answer (score 1):

Your `pokeData` is received via asynchronous action so by the time of rendering, your data may not be set yet.

You can check the availability of your data before actually rendering

```
{ (pokeData && pokeData.sprites) &&
   <img src={pokeData.sprites.front_default} alt=""/>
}
```

Comment: you can also do do it like this: ```<img src={pokeData?.sprites?.front_default} alt=""/>```, then you end up writing less code and is kinda easy to understand

Answer (score 0):

working example: [link - sandbox using optional_chaining](https://codesandbox.io/s/optionalchaining-hjxb7)

setPokeData will be asynchronous and the data availability in pokeData is going to take some time. Since pokeData's initial value is empty array `[]`, this `{pokeData.sprites.front_default}` would be `{[].sprites.front_default}` and you get undefined error.

you could use **optional chaining operator (?.)** to safely ignore if the key value is not available in the object.

`<img src={pokeData?.sprites?.front_default} alt=""/>`

ref:

- [why-react-setstate-usestate-does-not-update-immediately](https://linguinecode.com/post/why-react-setstate-usestate-does-not-update-immediately)
- [optional chaining operator](https://javascript.info/optional-chaining#optional-chaining)